# Apply STIX font to MathML CSS

Tags: css, mathml

I try to use this font for render a simple MathmML formula with this simple CSS but the formula not change,

```
.formula {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 10px;

    font-family: 'STIXGeneral';
}
```

or with

```
    @font-face
{
font-family: STIX;
src: url('STIXIntegralsD-Regular.ttf');

}

.formula {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 10px;

    font-family: 'STIX';
}
```

but nothing, the font is not applied, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

For the second one to work the ttf file would need to be in the same directory as the html file, and the browser you are using would need to be able to load ttf fonts as web fonts see http://caniuse.com/ttf  for a table of which browsers support ttf web fonts.

The first should work so long as you have the stix fonts installed locally and use class="formula" on your element (100  would be very light though).